# Escape character for jQuery within jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Here's my code :

```
$('div#fancy_notification').prepend('<a class="close" onclick="jQuery("#fancy_notification").css("display", "none"); return false;" href="#">test</a>');
```

This part doesn't render correctly, I guess I have to escape some characters... :

```
onclick="jQuery("#fancy_notification").css("display", "none"); return false;"
```

How can I do that? Is there a prettier way to achieve that?

Comment: this isnt a jquery way to add that close event.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('div#fancy_notification').prepend('<a class="close" onclick=\'jQuery("#fancy_notification").css("display", "none"); return false;\' href="#">test</a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a delegate/on function.

```
  $('#fancy_notification').prepend('<a id="close1" class="close" href="#">test</a>');

  $(document).on('click', '#close1', function(){
        $(this).css("display", "none");
        return false;
  });
```

I generally try to avoid inline script as much as possible.

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gqwUM/2/